# return value to function within a function

Tags: javascript

Trying to get a return value from getUrl function but it comes back as undefined.
 
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks
Here is the code:

```
function createXmlFicaRsi(xmlDoc,xmlFileName) {     
    var mystr = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><result><rows>"+strStor+"</rows></result>"
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
      jQuery("#fRsiGrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'xmlstring',
        datastr : mystr,
        colNames:['Year','Earnings', 'Amt<br/>Needed <br/>1 QC','Amt<br/>Needed <br/>4 QC','#<br/>of<br/> QCs','Monthly<br/>Under FRA','Yearly<br/>Under FRA','Monthly<br/> Yearly of<br/> Attain.<br/> FRA','Year of<br/> Attain. of<br/> FRA','YOC*','Sum of<br/>Post-1977<br/>YOCs'],
        colModel :[ 
            {name:'yearRsi', index:'yearRsi', width:55, resizable:false, align:'center', sorttype:'int'},
            {name:'earnRsi', index:'earnRsi', width:65, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false}, 
            {name:'1qcRsi', index:'1qcRsi', width:65, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false}, 
            {name:'4qcRsi', index:'4qcRsi', width:65, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false}, 
            {name:'numqcRsi', index:'numqcRsi', width:40, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false}, 
            {name:'mfra', index:'mfra', width:65, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false}, 
            {name:'yfra', index:'yfra', width:65, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false},
            {name:'myafra', index:'myafra', width:85, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false},
            {name:'yafra', index:'yafra', width:65, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false},
            {name:'yoc', index:'yoc', width:65, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false},          
            {name:'sumpost', index:'sumpost', width:60, resizable:false, align:'right', sortable:false} ],     
        rowNum:-1,      
        hidegrid: false,
        width: 760, 
        height: 460,
        shrinkToFit: false,         
        caption: '<span id=fRsiGrid_caption>FICA Earnings, QC, AET and YOC amounts after 1977</span>'       
      });     

      $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-th-column').css('height', '40px');
      $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div').css('height', '40px'); 
      $('.ui-jqgrid-title').css('font-size', '.8em');//Font size for title
      $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-th-column').css('font-size', '.7em');//Font size for header content 
      $('#fRsiGrid_caption').append("<span id='whatLink' style='font-size:large;color:blue;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer'>*</span>");     

    }); 
    $('#jqgh_1qcRsi').addClass("gridLink");
    $('#jqgh_4qcRsi').addClass("gridLink");
    $('#jqgh_mfra').addClass("gridLink");
    $('#jqgh_yfra').addClass("gridLink");
    $('#jqgh_myafra').addClass("gridLink");
    $('#jqgh_yafra').addClass("gridLink");
    $('#jqgh_yoc').addClass("gridLink");

    $("#jqgh_1qcRsi").click(function() {
        var nurl = getUrl("QueryView-QC");
        alert(nurl);        
    }); 
}

function getUrl(urlNm){
    DWREngine._execute(_ajaxConfig._cfscriptLocation, null, 'getUrls', urlNm, doQueryResults);
    function doQueryResults(r){     
        xmlDoc = loadXMLString(r);      
        y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("URL");

        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {            
            url = y[i].attributes.getNamedItem("val").nodeValue;            
            if (url == urlNm)
            {                           
                url = y[i].childNodes[0];
                //alert(url.nodeValue);
                url = url.nodeValue;
                return url;
            }           
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Works alright for me: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgBxy/) How are you calling anotherOne()?

Comment: Your code example is incomplete and doesn't demonstrate any issue. Please post code that accurately reproduces the issue you're having. Thanks.

Comment: Might it be because there is no return statement when the if fails in the getUrl function?

Comment: @DJ Quimby: I'd say you're probably describing the issue. Unfortunately it isn't clearly represented in the question.

Comment: @Noe: Saw your update, and added an answer. Actual code is *always* helpful. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **AJAX is asynchronous**

It appears as though you're making an AJAX request inside `getURL`.

Remember, AJAX requests are *asynchronous* by default. That means when you call `getURL`, the code after it executes ***immediately*** instead of waiting for the AJAX response.

Any code that relies on the response needs to be done in the callback to the AJAX request.

It appears as though your callback function is `doQueryResults`. Place the `alert()` in that function, and it should fire.

Comment: +1 because It's vaughan answering our questions from the grave!

Comment: @Raynos: I faked my death so I could pursue my aspirations as a JavaScript developer. I think I may have made a mistake.

Comment: Not bad for a 91 year old wearing a hat

Comment: @KooiInc: Yeah, my first programming job was in 1930's programming Hollerith machines for the *"Computing Tabulating Recording Corporation"*. Ever hear of them? They go by a different name these days.

Answer (score 2):

The inner functions are not activated, so running testOne() doesn't do anything. If you want to run it, use:

```
  function testOne() {
   (function inside() {
      //some other code
      (function anotherOne() {
          var nurl = getUrl("firstLink");
          alert(nurl);
      })();
   })()
  }
  testOne();
```

Or even

```
function testOne() {
   //some other ocde
   return function inside() {
      //some other code
       return function anotherOne() {
          var nurl = getUrl("firstLink");
          alert(nurl);
      };
   }
}
testOne()()();
```

but may be you should ask yourself: what's the use? :D

Comment: @KooiInc: I may be wrong, but I don't think that's the issue. OP stated that it comes back as *undefined*, so I take that to mean that the functions are invoked somehow. Hard to say though.

Comment: @patrick: dunno, getUrl with the right parameter is just working. It may also be something with that *some other code*. Ah well, I offered *a* solution, not *the* solution I suppose.

Comment: @KooiInc: Yeah, all we can do is speculate. Your solutions are certainly valid code solutions. I'm tempted to give you a + just for the `testOne()()();` ;o)

Comment: @patrick yep, I had fun with it too. Now let's see what the OP thinks. By the way: not being a native english speaker, what does OP stand for (apart from it being evidently the one that asked the question)? There are so many OPs! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OP

Comment: @patrick: scratch that. Found it on *stackmeta* faq: *O*riginal *P*oster. Had to read the FM first, right?

Comment: @KooiInc: Looks like we found our problem. Another *AJAX is asynchronous* issue. Amazing what a difference it makes to have the actual code in the question!

Comment: @patrick: right, another indeed. No offense, but AJAX *is* not asynchronous. That's why I seldom use the acronym (it is not Asynchronous, it does not have to use/return XML; the only characters that matter are *JA* for javascript (and I bet you can do 'AJAX' using client side vbscript too, knowing MS invented XHR). Better is XHR (XMLHttpRequest) or 'background remote request' or something. Its *default* mode is async, but you can perfectly run it synchronous (blocking, setting the third parameter of the `open` method to `false`).

Comment: @KooiInc: Yeah, I know. Thats why my answer says *"AJAX requests are asynchronous by default"*. Someone who knows enough to make the request *synchronous* usually knows enough to not have trouble with them in their default mode. :o)

Comment: ...still `XHR` isn't better in my opinion. X for XML is not required as you stated, and H for HTTP is not required either. But they did get the R right!

Comment: ...So, let's stick to R then, an elegant solution. "I'm running R, but I get no results from", "How to process data from R". "How do I do R without H"? The last one is for you to answer ;)

Comment: Hey, why not? It would save some typing! ;o) "How do I do R without H?" How about F or F (file or ftp)? So maybe we just need a fully descriptive term, like ASJXHJSTHFFR for *"Asynchronous or Synchronous Javascript and XML or HTML or JSON or Script or Text HTTP or FTP or FILE Request"*. ;o)

Comment: And we baptise it: AjaxHoistFever!

Answer (score 1):

Appears to work for me.  See my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nBTLB/

Comment: Aren't you just calling getURL directly, and not testing the inner functions?

Comment: Code was written for the original post, which didn't specify how to call the functions exactly at the time...

Comment: Ah - I'm just late on the scene as usual!

Comment: Np.  @Jon You can hit refresh a dozen times every few mins like me and try play _fastest fiddle_ :)

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with that you function is defined within another one

but it seems that getUrl is defined after testOne
maybe it hasn't been defined by the time anotherOne gets called?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get undefined is to call getUrl with an argument other than "firstLink".
Furthermore, the method getUrl should have an else statement with an alternative return when the provided argument is not "firstLink"